# Brand new miner on Windows 10, with 1060 GTX 6gb

Tags: cpp-ethereum, ethminer, windows, nvidia

I am a brand new miner, pretty much know nothing about programming (some C++ classes in school). Was using cryptocompare.com guide to get going, but ethminer.exe keeps crashing at the grabbing DAG step (after it was built). Any help to push me along is very much appreciated.

I am using Windows 10, with Nvidia 1060 GTX 6GB (driver 382.05, recent to the last month). FX-6300, OC'd to 3.9 (have HWmonitor open and see CPU load doesn't reach past ~40% when starting up ethminer). Geth and ethminer in D drive, regular HDD. 8 GB ram in system.

I installed Geth 1.6.5 yesterday, went in and started a new account. I was able to sync the blockchain to my computer; I have been using "`geth --rpc --fast --cache=1024`" in the command prompt.

I tried cpp-ethereum 1.2.8 and 1.2.4, and used the CUDA 0.9.4.1. All gave me the same issue. I could use ethminer -G -M command and it gave me trials with ~17 MH/s. But running "ethminer -G" ran a few lines, then crashed (windows prompt that ethminer.exe stopped working). Here is a copy of the command prompt window:

```
D:\Program Files>cd cpp-ethereum
D:\Program Files\cpp-ethereum>ethminer -G
Found suitable OpenCL device [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB] with 6442450944 bytes of GPU memory
miner  13:51:24.094|main  Getting work package...
JSON-RPC problem. Probably couldn't connect. Retrying in 1...
miner  13:51:26.116|main  Getting work package...
miner  13:51:26.120|main  Grabbing DAG for #7c4fb8a5ΓÇª
  i  13:51:27.813|<unknown>  Loading full DAG of seedhash: #3868abc5ΓÇª
miner  13:51:27.813|main  Got work package:
miner  13:51:27.817|main    Header-hash: 1a921b256f319cc49c67a9bba8bded456e8b3aaeffaff9a84fa1ef3dca320565
miner  13:51:27.821|main    Seedhash: 7c4fb8a5d141973b69b521ce76b0dc50f0d2834d817c7f8310a6ab5becc6bb0c
miner  13:51:27.826|main    Target: 0000000000006e1447e3081e1abbfd8c43e346c68150876c888b6f98e4edd880
  i  13:51:27.833|gpuminer0  workLoop 0 #00000000ΓÇª #7c4fb8a5ΓÇª
  i  13:51:27.835|gpuminer0  Initialising miner...
miner  13:51:28.334|main  Mining on PoWhash #1a921b25ΓÇª : 0 H/s = 0 hashes / 0.5 s
Using platform: NVIDIA CUDA
```

Ths above actually got a little bit further than it ever has, but still crahes immediately.

Here is the "-G -M" details:

```
D:\Program Files\cpp-ethereum>ethminer -G -M
Found suitable OpenCL device [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB] with 6442450944 bytes of GPU memory
Benchmarking on platform: { "platform": "NVIDIA CUDA", "device": "GeForce GTX 1060 6GB", "version": "OpenCL 1.2 CUDA" }
Preparing DAG...
Warming up...
  i  13:55:44.711|gpuminer0  workLoop 0 #00000000ΓÇª #00000000ΓÇª
  i  13:55:44.716|gpuminer0  Initialising miner...
Using platform: NVIDIA CUDA
Using device: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB(OpenCL 1.2 CUDA)
Printing program log
Creating one big buffer for the DAG
Loading single big chunk kernels
Mapping one big chunk.
Trial 1... Creating buffer for header.
Creating mining buffer 0
Creating mining buffer 1
12666071
Trial 2... 18861793
Trial 3... 18768218
Trial 4... 18081908
Trial 5... 17938448
min/mean/max: 12666071/17263287/18861793 H/s
inner mean: 18262858 H/s
Phoning home to find world ranking...
```

Thank you for the help! BTW how could I copy paste the command prompt text without the format changing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `--no-precompute` to your args list.  I was struggling with a similar issue on a very similar setup and this is what got me back up and running again.